# IP leakage after installing a VPN service

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-server

I have questions about how I can prevent IP leakage after installing a VPN service. For example, if I installed Shadowsocks, what should I do to prevent IP leakage? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try a different VPN system. I do not have this issue with IPsec VPN.

Comment: shadowsocks is a Proxy service, not a VPN provider.

Comment: Do you *know* that you have an IP leak?

Comment: You can visit a site like https://ipleak.net/ to test for leakages, and if there are any, find out the specific type and see if there is any advice for that type.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad. What VPN service? OpenVPN, as tagged? Is Ubuntu Server (again, tagged) the server or the client? Which software do you fear could leak the IP address? There are many protocols that could, but every day, fewer do.

Comment: @John What services do you provide, and can you explain about IPsec?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes you are right, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes.

Comment: @TechHorse Thanks for the introduction.

Comment: @DanielB 
Yes, I set up OpenVPN, Wireguard and Shadowsocks on my personal Ubuntu server, but after a while the IP is leaked and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: sounds like you need a killswitch on your VPN, so that when the VPN fails, the computer stops all network connections. for ShadowSocks, you need to configure your applications to use the proxy. I know there are some apps that will force proxying for all network communication (privoxy is the last one I tried, which clearly dates me) but I'm not sure what the current popular apps for this are.

Comment: What services do you provide, and can you explain about IPsec? .....   IPsec Cisco VPN server and NCP Secure Entry. No issue with IP address leaking.

Comment: You write that “after a while” the IP address is leaked. How did you determine this and after detecting the leak, was the VPN connection up or down?